# In plsql how can a function use an object declared in a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have a package(that is in beta, just want to make it work):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg1 AS
type pipeDefinition is record  
(
  str VARCHAR2(4000),
  num NUMBER,
);

 type pipeContainer is table of pipeDefinition;

   FUNCTION f1(x NUMBER) RETURN 
pipeContainer pipelined;

END pkg1;
```

and the package body

```
CREATE PACKAGE BODY pkg1 AS  

 FUNCTION f1(x NUMBER) RETURN 
  pipeContainer pipelined
  IS 
  BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..x LOOP
    PIPE ROW(pipeDefinition('i',i));
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
  END f1;
END pkg1;
```

my problems:

1if i try to run the above i get

"error at line:
PIPE ROW(pipeDefinition('i',i));
function pipeDefinition can not be found" (not exactly exactly what it said, but close)

2if i try to use pkg1.pipeDefinition instead i get the same error

"error at line:
PIPE ROW(pipeDefinition('i',i));
function pipeDefinition can not be found"

3if i try to add

```
type pipeDefinition is record  
(
  str VARCHAR2(4000),
  num NUMBER,
);

 type pipeContainer is table of pipeDefinition;
```

in the package body, it sais 
"can not declare more than 1 pipeContainer 
and more than 1 pipeDefinition"

4if i try to add

```
type pipeDefinition2 is record  
(
  str VARCHAR2(4000),
  num NUMBER,
);

 type pipeContainer2 is table of pipeDefinition2;
```

in the package body(and alter the pipeRow line with pipeDefinition2), it sais
"the object referenced is of a diferent kind as to the one the function is suposed to output"

5if i try to add 4 and make the function return pipeContainer2 pipelined it sais
"function mismatch package and body"

6if i try to add 6 and make function return pipeContainer2 pipelined in the package also i get
"pipeContainer2 not defined before using it " in the package creator

can anyone give me some hints?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Klas Lindbäck, you are my hero!

Solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg1 AS
type pipeDefinition is record  
(
  str VARCHAR2(4000),
  num NUMBER,
);

 type pipeContainer is table of pipeDefinition;

   FUNCTION f1(x NUMBER) RETURN 
pipeContainer pipelined;

END pkg1;
```

and the package body

```
CREATE PACKAGE BODY pkg1 AS  

 FUNCTION f1(x NUMBER) RETURN 
  outrec1 pipeDefinition;
  --removed: pipeContainer pipelined
  IS 
  BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..x LOOP
    --removed: PIPE ROW(pipeDefinition('i',i));
    --newLines:
    outrec1.str := 'a';
    outrec1.num := i;
    PIPE ROW(outrec1);
    --endNewLines.  
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
  END f1;
END pkg1;
```

and my new pointer function is finally complete! :"D

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(pkg1.f1(5));
|str | num|
 a   |   1
 a   |   2
 a   |   3
 a   |   4
 a   |   5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create or replace package pk2 as

  type c1 is ref cursor return employees%rowtype;

  type outrec is record (
    var_num number,
    var1 varchar2(50),
    var2 varchar2(50));

  type outrecset is table of outrec;

  function f_trans (c2 c1) return outrecset pipelined;

end pk2;



create or replace package body pk2 as

function f_trans(c2 c1) return outrecset pipelined is

  outrec1 outrec;
  outrec2 c2%rowtype;
begin

  loop
    fetch c2 into outrec2;

    exit when c2%notfound;

    outrec1.var_num := outrec2.employee_id;
    outrec1.var1 := outrec2.first_name;
    outrec1.var2 := outrec2.last_name;

    PIPE ROW(outrec1);  

    outrec1.var1 := outrec2.email;
    outrec1.var2 := outrec2.phone_number;

    PIPE ROW(outrec1);  

   END LOOP;

   RETURN;

  END f_trans;

END pk2;
```

please take hint from this code

data type for the record is not declared